# Unable to create new pages and upload images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have run into some trouble with Wordpress. I am trying to create another page, but I keep getting these errors:

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/customer/www/torkelv92.sg-host.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 736

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/customer/www/torkelv92.sg-host.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php:736) in /home/customer/www/torkelv92.sg-host.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9

Currently, I have tried to disable all plugins, change the theme in case that had a conflict, I have checked filepermissions in filezilla for the image upload, but nothing has changed there either. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. I had to go into PHPmyadmin and change auto increment from 500 to 1000 for it to go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a JavaScript conflict with plugins. What you can do is disable all plugins and enable them one at a time, Testing the page creation functionality.

If not work given method, please change the WordPress version.

Comment: I have alredy tried deactivating the plugins, and it seems like none of them are causing the isssue. Chaning the wordpress version did not work either